# MSAL Authentication in React application based on env selection

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm working on implementing MSAL authentication in my React-based application. My goal is to create a Login Control page where users can see buttons for DEV and PPD. When a user clicks one of these buttons, a MSAL authentication window popup will appear, allowing them to authenticate against Azure AD. Upon successful authentication, the user should be redirected to the home page.

I've successfully displayed the Login Control page and implemented Azure AD authentication. However, the issue I'm encountering is that after authentication, the redirection doesn't take users to the home page; instead, they remain on the Login Control page.

However, Instead of a dedicated Login Control page, I have opted to use a button within the `UnauthenticatedTemplate` for this demo.

**Also for some reason, the `isAuthenticated` is always false.**

App.tsx

```
const App = ({ envProps }) => {

  const [msalInstanceEnv, setUpdateMsalInstanceEnv] = useState("");
  const [msalInstanceFactory, setMSALInstanceFactory] = useState(null);
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const updateMSALUserEnvSelection = (selectedEnv: string) => {
    if (selectedEnv !== "") {
      setUpdateMsalInstanceEnv(selectedEnv);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (msalInstanceEnv) {
      setMSALInstanceFactory(_MSALInstanceFactory(msalInstanceEnv));
    }
  }, [msalInstanceEnv]);

    useEffect(() => {
    if (msalInstanceFactory) { 
      if(!isAuthenticated){
        msalInstanceFactory.loginPopup().then(() => {
          navigate('/home');
        }).catch(() => {})
      }
      }
  }, [msalInstanceFactory])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("isAuthenticated", isAuthenticated)
  })

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <MsalProvider instance={msalInstanceFactory}>
            <_MSALInterceptor loginEnv={msalInstanceEnv}>
              <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                  <MasterRoutes />
              </AuthenticatedTemplate>
            </_MSALInterceptor>
          </MsalProvider>
        ) : (
          <>
            <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
              //LoginControlPage with buttons.
              <Button onClick={() => updateMSALUserEnvSelection("DEV")}>Login DEV</Button>
            </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
          </>
        )}
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here I've provided all my Azure related configurations.

```
export const _environmentDEV = {
  production: false,
  azureB2C: {
      clientId: 'abc',
      redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      authorityDomain: '...',
      names: {
          signUpSignIn: '...',
          forgotPassword: '...',
      },
      authorities: {
          signUpSignIn: {
              authority:
               '...',
          },
          forgotPassword: {
              authority:
                  '...',
          },
      },
      authRequest: {
          scopes: [....],
      },
  },
}
```

I have multiple environments, so basically I am trying to set the MSAInstanceFactory based on the env selected i.e, either `DEV` or `PPD`.

```
const _environmentConfig = {
  DEV: {
    clientId: _environmentDEV.azureB2C.clientId,
    authority: _environmentDEV.azureB2C.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
    redirectUri: _environmentDEV.azureB2C.redirectUrl,
    knownAuthorities: [_environmentDEV.azureB2C.authorityDomain],
  }
};

export function _MSALInstanceFactory(loginEnv: string): IPublicClientApplication {
  const config = _environmentConfig[loginEnv];

  const instance = new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: config.clientId,
      authority: config.authority,
      redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
      knownAuthorities: config.knownAuthorities,
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie:
        window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 ||
        window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1,
    },
  });

  return instance;
}
```

```
const _getScopes = (loginEnv: string) => {
  switch (loginEnv) {
    case 'DEV':
      return _environmentDEV.azureB2C.authRequest.scopes
    default:
      return []
  }
}

export const _MSALInterceptor: React.FC<any> = ({loginEnv, children}: any) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal()
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
      const request = {
          scopes: _getScopes(loginEnv),
          account: accounts[0],
      }
      axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.origin
      axios.interceptors.request.use(
          async (config) => {
              const token = await instance.acquireTokenSilent(request)
              if (token) {
                // @ts-ignore
                  dispatch(LOGIN_SUCCESS(token))
                  config.headers = {
                      Authorization: `Bearer ${token.accessToken}`,
                      'Content-Type':
                          config.headers['content-type'] ??
                          'application/json',
                  }
                  navigate('/home');
              } else alert('no token present')
              return config
          },
          (error) => {
              Promise.reject(error)
          }
      )
  }
  }, [loginEnv])

  return <>{children}</>
}
```

```
export const MasterRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    {RouteComponents.map(({ url, component }, i) => ( 
        // @ts-ignore
        <Route key={i} path={url} element={<component />} />
    ))}
  </Routes>
)

export const RouteComponents = [
  { url: "/home", name:'Home', component: Dashboard },
  { url: "/contact", name:'Contact', component: Contact },
]
```

auth.slice.tsx

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

//type

const initialState: any = {
    loading: false,
    user: {} as any,
    error: '',
    isLogin: false,
}

const userToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    ? localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    : null

export const authReducer = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        LOGOUT_SUCCESS: (state) => {
            state.user = {} as any
            state.isLogin = false
        },
        LOGIN_SUCCESS: (state, data: any) => {
            state.isLogin = true
            state.user = {
                account: data.payload.account,
                accessToken: data.payload.accessToken,
                scopes: data.payload.scopes,
            }
        },
    }
})

export const { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGOUT_SUCCESS } = authReducer.actions
```

You kind help in this regard will highly be appreciated.